# How can I tell if a sentence is missing an optional subject marker?

Tags: grammar, subject-particle

I am reading BillyGo book and stumbled across the sentence 저는 오늘 기쁩니다.
I am a little confused when reading it, "today" is just kind of slipping in there without any particle,
so is "Happy" describing it? Can the noun today be "Happy", if so should this include the subject marker such as 저는 오늘이 기쁩니다, so now I can see that the verb "happy" is describing the noun "today". I don't think I am 100% on reading this sentence, I was hoping someone could explain it to me. Thanks

Comment: It is "I am happy today".

Comment: It shouldn’t be slipping. Whether you put that particle or not does make the sentence different. To me the latter sounds like “I like this day.” “Today is a pleasure to me.” (오늘 used as a noun object) whereas the former means “I am happy today.” (오늘 as an adverb)

Comment: Some words can be adverbs without any markers, and you cannot attach markers to them.

Answer (score 1):

오늘이 기쁩니다 doesn't work. it means 'today is happy'. 이 is subject particle, so 오늘이 기쁩니다 means the subject that feels happy is 'today'. This is weird.

저는 오늘 기쁩니다 means 'I am happy today'. 오늘 describes the entire sentence 저는 기쁩니다(I'm happy), explaining the time when I am happy is 'today'. In this case, 오늘 doesn't need a particle. For example, 저는 오늘에 기쁩니다 is weird.